# Create fixed value constraint for leading or left

Tags: ios, swift

Consider having dynamic (programmatically calculated) size and position for a view.

While I can easily set width and height to a constant, like:

```swift
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: mySize.width)
```

> Where `widthAnchor` is of `NSLayoutDimension` type.

But I get compile error for each of below:

```
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
myView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
```

> Where `leadingAnchor` and `leftAnchor` are both of `NSLayoutXAxisAnchor` type.

With error message:

```
No exact matches in call to instance method 'constraint'
```

#### Is there any way to have constant X/Y position using constraint(s)?

**Notes:**

**#1** `myView` is the root-view, without any-other-view, hence something like below is not possible:

```
myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myOtherView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

> But would not make much sense anyway, as now I would get same error, but while trying to give `myOtherView` a constant position.

**#2** Above code is `Swift 5`, but I tag `Obj-C` and `Obj-C++` too, as I know those languages, and would understand those answers as well.

### Example 2

While a dynamic-position is a general requirement, but to answer comments about why `myView` is a root-view, see:

```
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
        .isActive = true;

    // ...
} else {
    // Below gives error.
    myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.0)
        .isActive = true;

    // ...
}
```

> Basically, older iOS versions don't have safe-area anchor, hence there I need to use a constant.

Comment: What are you trying to do actually? Why do you want to set left/leading anchor to 0 if it is already a root view of a view controller?

Comment: @LeszekSzary see `Example 2` section; I tried to keep Q/A short, but you asked.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not clear to me what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: @LeszekSzary To explain the example's aim; older iOS versions don't have safe-area anchor yet, hence there I need to use a constant.

Comment: If your view is a root view of a view controller why do you even set any constraints on it? By default root view of a view controller already covers entire window.

Comment: @LeszekSzary A constraint avoids accidentally setting myView's frame, but instead of explaining a constraint's advantages, let's say I am creating `pinToSafeArea()` method (and doing nothing for older iOS version is not an option).

Comment: Yes I understand advantages of constraints but you should not set any constraints on the root view, you only set constraints on subviews of the root view so if you are setting any constraints on the root view of a view controller then you are doing something wrong. The root view of a view controller covers the entire window without setting any constraints on it.

Comment: @LeszekSzary that is only because `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is `true` by default, what if that is `false`, iOS can translate-to-constraint why not we?

Comment: @LeszekSzary I sense two or three down-votes in the air, but maybe we can make custom `NSLayoutAnchor` sub-class, or `NSLayoutConstraint` sub-class to begin with? (I mean, the sub-class' constructor would take constant and axis as parameter).

Comment: I do not know what you are trying to do but for sure you should leave the main root view as it is and do not set any constraints or change translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints on it. Setting left/right/top/bottom constraints to 0 on the main root view does not have any sense as that is default on all iOS versions. Whatever you are trying to achieve I can only recommend putting another view inside the root view and set constraints on this subview in relation to the root view.

Comment: @LeszekSzary I just changed my `UIView` extension's `pinToSafeArea()` method to simply do nothing if `superview` is `nil` :-(

Comment: @Top-Master - as has been noted, setting / changing constraints of the **root view** of a controller doesn't make any sense. You say *"older iOS versions don't have safe-area anchor, hence there I need to use a constant"* ... but again, why would you be trying to change the frame of the root view? Try editing your post and provide a clear, concrete example of what you're trying to do -- with, if possible, a couple screen-shots showing what's not working as expected. It's very, very difficult to offer help with abstract, unclear questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think this method `constraint(equalToConstant:)` is deprecated or no more available now.

You can use the like:

```
newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oldView.leadingAnchor) //without giving any constant value
newView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: oldView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0) //with some constant value
```

Comment: See question's edit; `myView` is the root-view, without any-other-view, hence something like above is not possible, but would not make much sense anyway, as now I would get same error, but while trying to give the other-view a constant position.

Comment: There must be some parentView otherwise adding constraint on the self doesn't make sense. 
In your case there must be `self.view`

Comment: Said `myView` is controller's `self.view`, yes, see `Example 2` section of question.

Comment: If your `myView` is `self.view` it means     1. `myView` doesn't need any constraint it covers entire screen without any constraint or     2. you are trying to add another subView to your `myView`. Hence there will be two view. 
- Adding constraint only on single view is not possible. What I think is constraint are like rope and to tie rope both end of the rope should be attached. So, there must be two view `superView` and `subView` to satisfy one constraint.

Comment: "it covers entire screen without any constraint" see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083564/create-fixed-value-constraint-for-leading-or-left?noredirect=1#comment129078605_73083564)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I worked-around the limitation:

```
extension UIView {

func pinToSafeArea() {

let myView = self;
if let parent = myView.superview {
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor)
            .isActive = true;

        // ...
    } else {
        myView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: parent.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0)
            .isActive = true;

        // ...
    }
} else {
    // Let's hope magically fills safe-area ;-)
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true;
}

} // func

} // extension
```